# Why are my line colors not showing in my KML file on Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps, kml

I have a KML file from an architect who says he colorized the lines (white, blue, red) and I see the  codes in the file itself so I know they are there. The proper colors do display in Google Earth, but NOT in google maps http://lonesomevalley.com/site-map-mapbox/ that I added  as a KML layer into MapBox. They also don't display when I bring into the Geojson.io tool so something must be wrong. I see that color is supported by google maps so wondering why it isn't working. Please help! Thanks in advance! My code can be downloaded here: http://evolv.com/lonesome.kml

Comment: @geocodezip so we need to adopt Geojson?

Comment: @Evolv please, update your code link. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

If I understand the question right, it was the same problem like I had for quit a while. Then someone gave me this quit simple solution.

The `colorcodes` in `kml` are in `BGR` format, while most other formats are the usual `RGB` format.

The conversion is quit simple: `RGB 'ff12dd'` will be in `BGR 'dd12ff'` (R and B just change) but in `kml` there must always be `'FF'` in front, so it will be `'FFdd12ff'`

Comment: I would like to add more to this answer. FF is the alpha (opaqueness) where 00 is transparent and FF is fully opaque. So KML expects color code in 8-bit HEX Code in the format - AABBGGRR

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell you if it's the same issue on your mapbox-implementation(mapbox isn't google maps)

The colors also will not be applied in a `google.maps.KmlLayer`

The issue seems to be that you've placed the `<Style/>`'s in `<Folder/>`'s

When you validate the KML ( http://www.kmlvalidator.com/home ) you'll see that the styles may not be found(and more errors) .

Possible solution( at least related to google-maps): Place the Styles outside of the Folders, as direct childs of `<Document/>`

Answer (score 0):

Okay after much trial and error working within the KML file, I finally consulted an expert who gave me a simple answer that worked! He said the easiest way to go about changing line colors and weight is through MapBox Editor itself. All you have to do is click on the Data tab, then the 3 horizontal lines button ("hamburger menu drawer icon")  to bring up the features. Then you can delete any feature you want from there or click on the feature to change its stroke color and weight. So EASY!!! Just be sure to hit save when done. And there is no Undo if you trash something by mistake so make sure to Save every once in a while and just back out of the project without saving in order to get back something you deleted by mistake.

So all in all I believe that KML files don't bring in the colors of lines correctly to MapBox and therefore need to be corrected through the editor itself.